# Extremely simple online multiplayer game

Tags: javascript, multiplayer, mmo, node.js

I am considering creating a simple multiplayer game, which focuses on physics and can accommodate up to 30 players per session. Very simple graphics, but smart physics (pushing, weight and gravity, balance) is required.
After some research I found a [good java script (framework ??) called box2d.js](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html)
I found the demo to be excellent. this is is kind of physics am looking for in my game.
Now, what other frameworks will I need? Node.js?? Prototype.js?? (btw, I found the latest versoin of protoype.js to be released in 2010...?? is this still supported? Should I avoid using it?)
What bout HTML 5 and Canvas? would I need them? websockets?

Am a beginner in web programming + game programming world. but I will learn fast, am computer science graduate. (but no much web expeience but know essentionals javascript, html, css..). I just need a guiding path to build my game.
Thanks

Comment: Simple - Multiplayer - Physics : pick two.

Comment: Where to get started, how to start making a particular game and which technology to use are all off topic for the site. See the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what kind of questions to ask here.

Answer (score 4):

Stop thinking in terms of frameworks and start thinking about what you want your *game* to do.

Does slapping a sticker on the box (okay, website) that says "Runs on Node.js!" or "Built for Box2D!" help sell more copies? Nope. Most users won't know and won't care.

You rattle off a lot of technologies, but it seems to me you're just excited to be building a game. You don't have a plan yet. Start with that.

Start simple. First, estimate how long it will take you to build a game like Tetris in JavaScript. 30 minutes? Longer? Write it down.

Build your simple Tetris clone. Ask questions if you get stuck. Now look at your estimate again. How off were you? By what margin?

You can now go either way:

- Keep building increasingly complex games, until you end up with a game that feels your own. (programmer)
- Keep expanding upon your simple game's design, how you can tweak it until it's the best Tetris ever. (designer)

As for your actual question: Box2D is a very good physics framework, but it's going to be impossible to get clients to sync up if you don't know anything about physics, networking or game programming in general.

Comment: I know what my game need to do. But I need to know which technologies to learn before starting with the project.
I don't have experience in javascript and in game programming, once i know the right path, then I get the feel of the complexity of tools/coding required then I start with something only then I can estimate time.
Now for synching, won't node.js help me in synching up clients..?.

Comment: @Postscripter the path is: pick one, follow it. If it doesn't suit you, pick another. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Postscripter Sure, canvas + box2d + node.js + socket.io. Go ahead. Now write some code! You'll learn your tools by using them.